# modifying variables outside of module python using from x import *

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, modularity

Lets suppose i have a function inside a module that changes the value of a global variable.

```
test = True

def foo():
    global test
    test = not test
    return
```

If i call foo() inside the module that the function was written the value of test will be changed as I want.

However if on my new module i try to call foo using the "from module import *" statement the variable wont change its value. I'm aware this is the expected behaviour, as the variable on my new module is just a copy of the original one, so the changes do not affect the original.

What i wanted to know if there was some kind of workaround that i could do to call the function on my new module and have its original value changed.

I know that i could use "import module" and then module.whatever to make it work, but since i want to restrict the access functions of my module using "__ all __" this isn't an option.

Any insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: The cleanest solution would probably be to just not use a global state.  Make a class that you can create instances of and have the state managed internally, or keep the state entirely local within functions, and just pass it to/from functions as needed.

Comment: Your explanation for why you cannot use `import module` doesn't make any sense, i.e. "but since i want to restrict the access functions of my module using "__ all __" this isn't an option." Note using `from module import *` is a bad practice in all but a few, specific use-case, none of which seem to describe your use case. So probably, the answer is just to use `import module`

Comment: But yes, I'll second the suggestion to avoid mutable global state to begin with, which is a classic anti-pattern.

Comment: Yeah I also agree its bad practice. I'm just doing this way because its a project for a class i'm taking and one of the requirements that was given was to have all the functions and variables that i will be using in other modules specified in "__ all __", so if i end up using "import module" directly it becomes pointless. Of course I simplified what the requirement is but just to make it more clear on why i chose to make things that way.

Comment: "using in other modules specified in "__ all __", so if i end up using "import module" directly it becomes pointless" So what if it is pointless? Better a pointless `__all__` than a poorly designed program.

Comment: Anyway, you are basically asking "how can I use this feature without using this feature".